# How do setters work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, getter-setter

Specifically, how does it work in relation to this Codecadamy example?

```
let person = {
  _name: 'Lu Xun',
  _age: 137,
  set age(ageIn) {
    if (typeof ageIn === 'number') {
      this._age = ageIn;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Invalid input');
      return 'Invalid input';
    }
  }

};
```

It doesn't make sense to me why they put the ageIn inside of age(), what does it do?

Thanks!

Comment: It’s the value being set. `person.age = 50` would be like `person.age(50)` if you removed the `set` keyword.

Comment: So it's like `let age = ageIn`?  It 'sets' ageIn = to age?

Comment: No, not at all. It’s a function that gets called with whatever you tried to set `age` to as an argument.

Comment: Okay, so it's used as the same value as _age since _age shouldn't be edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setter is a function that is executed whenever you are trying to change a parameter.

```
set age(ageIn)
```

In the above setter function they are trying to identify if the the parameter that they are trying to set is a number before assigning it to _age property of the object. This method is only called if user is setting value as person.age=140 and it will update person._age as 140.

However if user is trying to update the _age property directly it will not execute this method and will directly update the person._age

This is a useful resource to get a bit more idea about setters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Hope this helps. Happy coding